# Gradle fails to resolve spring dependency

Tags: maven, gradle, spring-data, parent-pom

I am trying to build my project with the following `build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.1.RELEASE')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:1.2.2.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.7.0.RC1')

    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-spring-service-connector')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector')

    compile 'org.springframework:spring-test:4.1.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'de.grundid.opendatalab:geojson-jackson:1.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.5.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4'

    testCompile('junit:junit')
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

I added the milestone repository because I need the spring-data-mongodb 1.7.0.RC1 dependency. However, there seems to be something wrong with the references of the parent-poms because gradle is unable to fetch the following dependency: `org.springframework.data.build:spring-data-parent:1.6.0.RC1`

It exits with the following error:

```
Could not find org.springframework.data.build:spring-data-parent:1.6.0.RC1.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/data/build/spring-data-parent/1.6.0.RC1/spring-data-parent-1.6.0.RC1.pom
    https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/data/build/spring-data-parent/1.6.0.RC1/spring-data-parent-1.6.0.RC1.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/build/spring-data-parent/1.6.0.RC1/spring-data-parent-1.6.0.RC1.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/build/spring-data-parent/1.6.0.RC1/spring-data-parent-1.6.0.RC1.jar
```

The output of the `gradlew build --debug` command can be found here: http://pastebin.com/seYRMFQP

The command additionally produced the following output to stdout: http://pastebin.com/atcWQsKF

I already tried to clean my local gradle cache but it did not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience, the artifact is currently misplaced in the [release](http://repo.spring.io/release/) repository, though it should be in [milestone](http://repo.spring.io/milestone/).

We'll move it to milestone asap. Until that happens please add the release repository `url 'https://repo.spring.io/release'` to your build.

Comment: the artifacts have been moved and are now available via the milestone repository.

Comment: What form does this need to take in the `build.gradle` file now?

Answer (score 0):

seems the repositories you defined in your build do not contain the libraries you're looking for. but it seems the lib is available in jcenter. to add jcenter add the following snippet to your build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

cheers,
René